# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when uploading csv

Tags: sql, database

I am getting the following error message when trying to upload a csv file.

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`drsurgery`.`appointments`, CONSTRAINT `appointments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DoctorID`) REFERENCES `doctors` (`DoctorID`))

I have three tables
Patient- PatientID as primary key
Doctor- DoctorID as primary key
Appointment-PatientID and DoctorID as composite primary key and date as another attribute

Any help would be appreicated

Thanks

Comment: The error message says it all. Check the foreign keys.

Comment: You are inserting a record in appointments with a DoctorID which does not exists in the table Doctor